# Example of a comutative ring without divisors of 0 which is not a domain

Tags: ring-theory

I know i have to look for something like a Domain but without the neutral element of multiplication but i Just cant think of an example, can somebody help me?

Comment: $2\mathbb Z{}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest okwill check

Comment: @MikeEarnest yeah, i realised after i typed haha

Answer (score 0):

Any nontrivial ideal in any integral domain.

Of course, you will have to know some integral domains that aren't fields to find these.